# Filesystem-ACLs (setfacl) Equivalent to "mkdir -p" for recursive handling of ACLs

Tags: permissions, acl

Following directory-structure is given

```
drwx------  root  root  /path/to/must_be_accessible
drwx------  root  root  /path/to/not_allowed1
drwx------  root  root  /path/to/not_allowed2
drwx------  root  root  /path/to/not_allowed3
```

User **read_only** should be able to read all files under **/path/to/must_be_accessible**

Way to go

```
#># Give read_only-user read-access to the path
#>setfacl -m u:read_only:x  /path
#>setfacl -m u:read_only:x  /path/to
#>setfacl -m u:read_only:rx /path/to/must_be_accessible

#># Set default for future files / dirs and all actual files
#>setfacl -m d:u:read_only:rX,u:read_only:rX    /path/to/must_be_accessible
```

Is there an equivalent to "mkdir -p" for applying the execute-permission to the read_only-user for the parent-directories? Did I miss anything?

**Clarification:**

The following structure needs to be implemented

```
# ls -lR
.:
drwx--x---+ 3 root root 15 16. Sep 16:47 path

./path:
drwx--x---+ 6 700 root 88 16. Sep 16:47 to

./path/to:
drwx--x---+ 2 700 root 6 16. Sep 16:47 must_be_accessible
drwx------. 2 700 root 6 16. Sep 16:47 not_allowed1
drwx------. 2 700 root 6 16. Sep 16:47 not_allowed2
drwx------. 2 700 root 6 16. Sep 16:47 not_allowed3
```

The ACLs should look something like

```
# getfacl --recursive path
# file: path
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
user:read_only:--x
group::---
mask::--x
other::---

# file: path/to
# owner: 700
# group: root
user::rwx
user:read_only:--x
group::---
mask::--x
other::---

# file: path/to/must_be_accessible
# owner: 700
# group: root
user::rwx
user:read_only:r-x
group::---
mask::r-x
other::---

# file: path/to/not_allowed1
# owner: 700
# group: root
user::rwx
group::---
other::---

# file: path/to/not_allowed2
# owner: 700
# group: root
user::rwx
group::---
other::---

# file: path/to/not_allowed3
# owner: 700
# group: root
user::rwx
group::---
other::---
```

Question is if there is any chance of not setting the x-Bit on every path above must_be_accessible (a shortcut...).

Comment: Are you looking for the `--recursive` option of setfacl?

Comment: I don't think so. As far as I understand this option, it is applied recursive to subdirectories and not to the parentdirectories.

Comment: I think your question needs some clarification. `mkdir -p` doesn't "recurse through parent directories", it creates subdirectories as they become needed along the path. Could you show us your expected output of `ls` (for your structure), along with some `getfacl` calls on the elements that do not match your needs?

Comment: I will das this tommorow. But I want exactly this. Put all neccesary execute Bits als they become needed.